# Oracle change dbtimezone

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timezone

My database was configured with an `dbtimezone=+2:00`:

When my application sends a date which has a timezone, does Oracle automatically translate the date to its `dbtimezone` and store it in the column?

When my application asks for a field date, does Oracle automatically translate it to the application timezone?

In order to be consistency with business rules, I wanted to change this `dbtimezone` to UTC. So I made the `alter database set time_zone='UTC'` command, I restarted the oracle server and now the `select dbtimezone from dual;` command returns "UTC".

But, all fields date in DB haven't changed (no change -2 hours from GMT+2 to UTC). When I ask the sysdate, it returns the GMT+2 date ... I try to change my SQL Developer configuration timezone to UTC but it didn't change anything. Do I have an issue of Oracle session parameters that convert my DB data to GMT+2 before displaying it ?

Finally, does anyone have a good practice to make this change ? (change the database timezone and existing date to a new timezone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're doing is changing the database time zone setting, then you are only going to notice any change in output if your data is stored with the [`TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006169) type.

I don't recommend that though. It would be much better if your data was just stored in a regular [`TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006050) field and was already set to UTC.

You should read the documentation about all of the different [date and time datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1005983), so you understand how each of these types works and differs from the other.

Comment: After more digging in my side, I founded changing the database session time_zone don't translate simple timestamp field. As you said Matt, if I wanted that, I have to use `TimeStampTZ` column type.